# Model building and selection using Hosmer et al. 2013. Applied Logistic Regression in R

Tags: r, logistic, model-selection, regression-strategies

This is my first post on StackExchange, but I have been using it as a resource for quite a while, I will do my best to use the appropriate format and make the appropriate edits. Also, this is a multi-part question. I wasn't sure if I should split the question into several different posts or just one. Since the questions are all from one section in the same text I thought it would be more relevant to post as one question.

I am researching habitat use of a large mammal species for a Master's Thesis. The goal of this project is to provide forest managers (who are most likely not statisticians) with a practical framework to assess the quality of habitat on the lands they manage in regard to this species. This animal is relatively elusive, a habitat specialist, and usually located in remote areas. Relatively few studies have been carried out regarding the distribution of the species, especially seasonally.  Several animals were fitted with GPS collars for a period of one year. One hundred locations (50 summer and 50 winter) were randomly selected from each animal's GPS collar data. In addition, 50 points were randomly generated within each animal's home range to serve as "available" or "pseudo-absence" locations. The locations from the GPS collars are coded a 1 and the randomly selected available locations are coded as 0.

For each location, several habitat variables were sampled in the field (tree diameters, horizontal cover, coarse woody debris, etc) and several were sampled remotely through GIS (elevation, distance to road, ruggedness, etc). The variables are mostly continuous except for 1 categorical variable that has 7 levels.

My goal is to use regression modelling to build resource selection functions (RSF) to model the relative probability of use of resource units. I would like to build a seasonal (winter and summer) RSF for the population of animals (design type I) as well as each individual animal (design type III).

I am using R to perform the statistical analysis.

The **primary text** I have been using is…

- "Hosmer, D. W., Lemeshow, S., & Sturdivant, R. X. 2013. Applied Logistic Regression. Wiley, Chicester".

The majority of the examples in Hosmer et al. use STATA, **I have also been using the following 2 texts for reference with R**.

- "Crawley, M. J. 2005. Statistics : an introduction using R. J. Wiley,
  Chichester, West Sussex, England."
- "Plant, R. E. 2012. Spatial Data Analysis in Ecology and Agriculture 
  Using R. CRC Press, London, GBR."

I am currently following the steps in **Chapter 4 of Hosmer et al. for the "Purposeful Selection of Covariates"** and have a few questions about the process. I have outlined the first few steps in the text below to aid in my questions.

1. Step 1: A univariable analysis of each independent variable (I used a
   univariable logistic regression). Any variable whose univariable test
   has a p-value of less than 0.25 should be included in the first
   multivariable model.
2. Step 2: Fit a multivariable model containing all covariates
   identified for inclusion at step 1 and to assess the importance of
   each covariate using the p-value of its Wald statistic. Variables
   that do not contribute at traditional levels of significance should
   be eliminated and a new model fit. The newer, smaller model should be
   compared to the old, larger model using the partial likelihood ratio
   test.
3. Step 3: Compare the values of the estimated coefficients in the
   smaller model to their respective values from the large model. Any
   variable whose coefficient has changed markedly in magnitude should
   be added back into the model as it is important in the sense of
   providing a needed adjustment of the effect of the variables that
   remain in the model. Cycle through steps 2 and 3 until it appears that all of the important variables are included in the model and those excluded are clinically and/or statistically unimportant. Hosmer et al. use the "*delta-beta-hat-percent*"
   as a measure of the change in magnitude of the coefficients. They
   suggest a significant change as a *delta-beta-hat-percent* of >20%. Hosmer et al. define the *delta-beta-hat-percent* as 
   $\Delta\hat{\beta}\%=100\frac{\hat{\theta}_{1}-\hat{\beta}_{1}}{\hat{\beta}_{1}}$.
   Where $\hat{\theta}_{1}$ is the coefficient from the smaller model and $\hat{\beta}_{1}$ is the coefficient from the larger model.
4. Step 4: Add each variable not selected in Step 1 to the model
   obtained at the end of step 3, one at a time, and check its
   significance either by the Wald statistic p-value or the partial
   likelihood ratio test if it is a categorical variable with more than
   2 levels. This step is vital for identifying variables that, by
   themselves, are not significantly related to the outcome but make an
   important contribution in the presence of other variables. We refer
   to the model at the end of Step 4 as the *preliminary main effects
   model*.
5. Steps 5-7: I have not progressed to this point so I will leave these
   steps out for now, or save them for a different question.

**My questions:**

1. In step 2, what would be appropriate as a traditional level of
   significance, a p-value of <0.05 something larger like <.25?
2. In step 2 again, I want to make sure the R code I have been using for the partial likelihood test is correct and I want to make sure I am interpreting the results correctly. Here is what I have been doing…`anova(smallmodel,largemodel,test='Chisq')` If the p-value is significant (<0.05) I add the variable back to the model, if it is insignificant I proceed with deletion?
3. In step 3, I have a question regarding the *delta-beta-hat-percent* and when it is appropriate to add an excluded variable back to the model. For example, I exclude one variable from the model and it changes the $\Delta\hat{\beta}\%$ for a different variable by >20%. However, the variable with the >20% change in $\Delta\hat{\beta}\%$ seems to be insignificant and looks as if it will be excluded from the model in the next few cycles of Steps 2 and 3. How can I make a determination if both variables should be included or excluded from the model? Because I am proceeding by excluding 1 variable at a time by deleting the least significant variables first, I am hesitant to exclude a variable out of order.
4. Finally, I want to make sure the code I am using to calculate $\Delta\hat{\beta}\%$ is correct. I have been using the following code. If there is a package that will do this for me or a more simple way of doing it I am open to suggestions.

   `100*((smallmodel$coef[2]-largemodel$coef[2])/largemodel$coef[2])`

Comment: out of curiosity what is the species  that you are studying ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

None of those proposed methods have been shown by simulation studies to work.  Spend your efforts formulating a complete model and then fit it.  Univariate screening is a terrible approach to model formulation, and the other components of stepwise variable selection you hope to use should likewise be avoided.  This has been discussed at length on this site.  What gave you the idea in the first place that variables should sometimes be removed from models because they are not "significant"?  Don't use $P$-values or changes in $\beta$ to guide any of the model specification.

Comment: Would you be able to expand on this with proven methods for model specification?

Comment: Use domain knowledge.

Comment: Yes, domain knowledge + a healthy dose of disbelief in simplicity, e.g., don't assume continuous variables act linearly unless you have prior data demonstrating linearity.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to read my question and respond. I got the ideas I proposed in my question from "Applied Logistic Regression" as I cited above in my question. I chose to use this text as reference because it is commonly cited in literature relating to species distribution modelling and because it was recommended by my committee members. 
If none of the methods I proposed are suitable, is there a method for formulating and fitting a model you suggest? There seems to be a lot of debate in the literature about the correct methods to use.

Comment: The OP is citing a mainstream text in its third edition with authors who have made great contributions to the field. Other points made in the question are discussed in other influential texts (Agresti, Gelman). I bring this up not because I agree with this strategy, but rather to note that these strategies
are advised in recent, mainstream texts by respected statisticians. In sum: although there is plenty of literature advising against this, it does not seem to be rejected by the statistical community.

Comment: That is quite misguided in my humble opinion.  The strategies pushed so hard in some texts have *never* been validated.  Authors who do not believe in simulation put themselves at risk for advocating the use of methods that do not work as advertised.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I was seeking your input on the comment "what gave you the idea in the first..". My confusion is that these suggestions are not coming from sources that lack statistical peer review, but in many cases elected fellows of the ASA. For those of us in applied work, these seem like reasonable sources.

Comment: I'm not sure why you conclude that.  I'm an ASA fellow and have made my share of mistakes.  There are a lot of statistics books by famous statisticians that contain egregious errors.

Comment: Yes, I know. I refer to your text and papers often,  and its one of the sources I have used to arrive at my  conclusion disagreeing with the above strategy. I am simply conveying the dilemma of the applied user. We cannot test everything. We rely on experts, such as you.

Comment: @julieth You have summed up a lot of my frustrations over the past few months. I care about this project a great deal, it is my Masters Thesis and my first research project. In addition there are people who care about the results. I want to do the analysis correctly, but it seems all of the methods suggested by my committee, the text I have consulted, and previous studies with this species are incorrect. My statistical knowledge is increasing daily, but it is still quite limited. I find it hard to know how to proceed when prominent statisticians are at odds over the issue.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I am very grateful that you have taken the time to give your input on my question. I am wondering if you could help clear a few more things up. Are you advocating that maybe GLM is not a appropriate approach to this problem or that the specific methods I was using are inappropriate? I am curious about your RmS package and am currently reading over the RmS section on your website and have requested your book.  When you refer to simulation are you talking about machine learning approaches like boosted regression trees, Maxent, and random forest?

Comment: Look at my online course notes.  GLM can be a wonderful tool.  Formulate your model using your subject matter knowledge and the literature.  No need for moving variables in and out of the model.

Comment: @GNG: FH is referring to simulation as a way of showing that this approach to model selection actually does what it's supposed to do (presumably to improve the accuracy of your model's predictions) in typical applications. Your (astute) questions highlight its rather arbitrary, ad hoc, nature - basing variable inclusion on an indeterminate number of significance tests at "traditional" levels can't be shown by theory to guarantee the optimization of anything.

Comment: @GNG: BTW, if RMS seems too hard read [Steyerberg (2009), *Clinical Prediction Models*](http://www.springer.com/medicine/internal/book/978-0-387-77243-1) first.

Answer (score 5):

Methods specified for variable selection using statistic such as P, stepwise regression in the classic text Hosmer et al should at all cost be avoided.

Recently I stumbled upon an article that was published in the international journal of forecasting entitle "[Illusions of predictability](http://emresoyer.com/Publications_files/Soyer%20%26%20Hogarth_2012.pdf)" and a commentory on this article by [Keith ord](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2016195). I would highly recommend both these article as they clearly show that using regression statistic is often misleading. Follwoing is a screenshot of Keith Ord's article that shows by simulation why step wise regression (uses p statistic) for variable selection  is bad.

[image]

Another wonderful article by [Scott Armstrong](http://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1190&context=marketing_papers) that appeared in the same issue of the journal shows why one should be very cautious on using regression analysis on non-experimental data with case studies. Ever since I read these articles I avoid using regression analysis to draw causal inferences on non-experimental data. As a practitioner, I wish I had read articles like this many years which would have saved me from making bad decisions and avoiding costly mistakes.

On your specific problem, I don't think randomized experiments are possible in your case, so I would recommend that you use [cross validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)) to select variables. A nice worked out example is available in this [free online book](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/5/3) on how you would use predictive accuracy to select variables. It also many othervariable selction methods, but I woud restrict to cross validation.

I personally like the quote from Armstrong "Somewhere I encountered the idea that statistics was supposed to aid communication. Complex regression methods and a flock of diagnostic statistics have taken us in the other direction"

Below is my own opinion. I'm not a statistician.

- As a biologist I think you would appreciate this point. Nature is very complex, **assuming** logistic function and no interaction among variables does not occur in nature. In addition, logistic regression has following [assumptions](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/webbooks/logistic/chapter3/statalog3.htm):
- The true conditional probabilities are a logistic function of the
  independent variables.
- No important variables are omitted. No extraneous variables are included.
- The independent variables are measured without error.
- The observations are independent.
- The independent variables are not linear combinations of each other.

I would recommend classification and regression tree (CART(r)) as an alternative over logistic regression for this type of analysis because it is assumptions free:

1. Non parametric/Data Driven/No assumptions that your output probablities follow logistic function.
2. Non linear
3. allows complex variable interaction.
4. Provides highly interpretable visual trees that a non statistician like forest managers would appreciate.
5. Easily handles missing values.
6. Dont need to be a statistician to use CART!!
7. automatically selects variables using cross validation.

CART is a trademark of Salford Systems. See this [video](http://www.salford-systems.com/products/cart/videos#introduction-to-cart) for introduction and history of CART. There are also other videos such as cart - logistic regrssion hybrids in the same website. I would check it out. an open source impentation in R is called [Tree](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tree/index.html), and there are many other packages such as rattle available in R. If I find time, I will post the first example in Homser's text using CART. If you insist on using logistic regression, then I would at least use methods like CART to select variables and then apply logistic regression.

I personally prefer CART over logistic regression because of aforementioned advantages. But still, I would try both logistic regression and CART or CART-Logistc Regression Hybrid, and see which gives better **predictive accuracy** and also more importantly better **interpretatablity** and choose the one that you feel would "communicate" the data more clearly.

Also, FYI CART was rejected by major statistical journals and finally the inventors of CART came out with a monograph. CART paved way to modern and highly successful machine learning algorithms like Random Forest(r), Gradient Boosting Machines (GBM), Multivariate Adaptive Regression Splines all were born. Randomforest and GBM are more accurate than CART but less interprettable (black box like) than CART.

Hopefully this is helpful. Let me know if you find this post useful ?

Comment: No.  The logistic model does not make more assumptions than other models.  It's main unique assumption is that $Y$ is truly all-or-nothing.  CART is hugely outperformed by logistic regression.  CART effectively fits *far* more parameters than logistic regression because it allows for all possible interactions.  The irony is that a method that allows maximum flexibility is more conservative than a more structured method.  You'll find that in order for CART models to be well-calibrated you have to prune the model down to have small predictive discrimination.

Comment: This answer jumps from general comments, many of which seem uncontroversial at least to me, to a highly specific and rather personal endorsement of CART as the method of choice. You're entitled to your views, as others will be entitled to their objections. My suggestion is that that you flag the twofold flavour of your answer rather more clearly.

Comment: Logistic regression is a generalised linear model, but otherwise it is defensible as, indeed well motivated as, a naturally nonlinear model (in the sense that it fits curves or equivalent, not lines or equivalent, in the usual space) that is well suited to binary responses. The appeal to biology here is double-edged; historically logistic models for binary responses were inspired by models for logistic growth (e.g. of populations) in biology!

Comment: The Soyer et al. paper, the Armstrong paper, and commentaries are all very good. I have been reading over them this weekend. Thank you for suggesting them. Not being a statistician I cannot comment on using CART over logistic regression. However, your answer is very well written, helpful, and has received comments that are insightful. I have been reading up on machine learning methods such as CART, MaxEnt, and boosted regression trees and am planning on discussing them with my committee to get their insight. When I get some free time, the CART video should be interesting as well.

Comment: See http://www.citeulike.org/user/harrelfe/tag/cart for some papers showing that single tree methods like cart are not competitive.  That is why random forests, bagging, etc. were invented.

Comment: YES CART is less accurate than random forest but highly interpret-able. It is going to be a trade-off between accuracy and interpretablity.

Comment: With a smile I think we can reverse your comments on linear models and insist that far from being assumption-free, or even assumption-light, CART assumes that reality is like a tree (what else?). If you think that nature is a smoothly varying continuum you should run in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're trying to predict the presence of the species with a presence/background approach, which is well documented in journals such as Methods in Ecology and Evolution, Ecography, etc. Maybe the R package dismo is useful for your problem. It includes a nice vignette. Using the dismo or other similar package implies to change your approach to the problem, but I believe it's worth to have a look at.

Comment: I did look into "dismo" and it was a very interesting read. The 2008 article by Elith et al. in the Journal of Animal Ecology was also very helpful. The example data and walk through are very helpful. I am curious if boosted regression trees are what I should be using or if there is a more appropriate method?

Comment: There is not a specific method that can be called as the best. I guess boosted regression trees are good, but there are other options, for example glm and Maxent. The latter is very popular. If you want to get very familiar with the field of species distribution modelling, I'm afraid there's a lot to read and maybe that's far from your needs. But now that you are aware of dismo and papers like Elith's, you are in a position to do your own judgement and look for the information you need.

Comment: GLM is the method I have been using; my question was regarding model selection using GLM. I would like to continue to use GLM if I could just find an appropriate way to formulate models. Maxent is only appropriate for presence-only data, if I were running an analysis on the GPS collar data with just variables derived remotely I would probably use it. However, while sampling in the field I also sampled pseudo-absence points. I asked about the boosted regression trees because that seems to be specifically what dismo package is for.

Comment: What keeps you from just specifying a model?  Why the great uncertainty in what should be in the model?  Why the need for model selection using GLM?

Comment: @FrankHarrell The goal of this project is to provide forest managers with a practical framework to assessing the quality of habitat on the lands they manage in regard to this species. I have >30 variables that were sampled in the field plus 5 more that were sampled remotely and only 1,100 data points. The species I am studying is a niche animal that is usually located in remote areas and few studies have been carried out on it with GPS data. My uncertainty about leaving all of the variables in the model comes from everything I have been taught about collinearity and over-fitting.

Comment: I'm afraid you're mixing some concepts. (1) in fact maxent is a presence/background data, or presence/pseudo-absence data. So, maxent uses the presence-only data and adds some points from the landscape, that is, the background/pseudo-absences. Thus, it can be used in your case. (2) GLM were designed to be used with 'true' absences. However, GLM has been adapted for presence/pseudo-absence data. (3) dismo package offers boosted regression trees but not only. You can fit GLM as well, just follow one of the package's vignettes (there are 2).

Comment: If your question is about which variables you should include as predictors, take a look at these papers: Sheppard 2013. How does selection of climate variables affect predictions of species distributions? A case study of three new weeds in New Zealand. Weed Research; Harris, et al. 2013. To Be Or Not to Be? Variable selection can change the projected fate of a threatened species under future climate. Ecol. Manag. Restor.

Comment: The thought that variable selection techniques somehow reduce overfitting is strange.  The apparent savings of variables from reducing the model is completely an illusion when the reduction comes from the data themselves.

Comment: @GNG: "My uncertainty about leaving all of the variables in the model comes from everything I have been taught about collinearity and over-fitting" - *Does* your model contain highly collinear predictors? *Is* your model over-fitting?